# python: finding the value of a random variable for a cdf

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, normal-distribution, cdf

I apologize in advance if this is poorly worded.

If I have a stdDev = 1, mean = 0, `scipy.stats.cdf(-1, loc = 0, scale = 1)` will give me the probability that a normally distributed random variable will be `<= -1`, and that is `0.15865525393145707`.

Given 0.15865..., how do I find the value that gives me -1?

i.e.  `value(cdf = 0.15865, loc = 0, scale = 1)`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

edit: you actually need import `norm` from `scipy.stats`.

I found the answer. You need to use `ppf` in `scipy.stats` which stands for ["percent point function"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html).

So let's say you have a normal distribution with stdDev = 1, and mean = 0 and you want to find the value at which the random variables will be below ~15% of the time. Just use:

`value = norm.ppf(0.15, loc = 0, scale = 1)`

This will return ~ -1, likewise if you do:

`cdf = norm.cdf(-1, loc = 0, scale = 1)`

This will return ~ 0.15 or 15%.

Cool beans.

Comment: For the record, `ppf` is what is more commonly called a "quantile" function. I don't know why they used a nonstandard name.